# Extract the Values from data set using ast and got empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

Here's the data set:

```
[{"meal": "MY food", "dishes": [{"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "412"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "29"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "24"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "21"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "258"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "29"}], "name": "my - McDonalds Espresso Pronto\u00ae Flat White, 2 TALL"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "170"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "25"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "5"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "20"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "260"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "2"}], "name": "Quest Bar - Banana Nut Muffin Natural Protein Bar, 60 g"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "176"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "33"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "1"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "5"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "195"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "0"}], "name": "Uncle Tobys Australia - Vita Brits, 3 Biscuits 33.3g"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "342"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "34"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "12"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "24"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "402"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "34"}], "name": "Pauls - Smarter White Milk, 600 ml"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "180"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "22"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "7"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "21"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "310"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "1"}], "name": "Quest Bar - Cookies and Cream, 1 bar"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "180"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "46"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "0"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "0"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "100"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "22"}], "name": "Gu Sports - Chomps, 8 pieces"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "170"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "25"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "5"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "20"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "260"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "2"}], "name": "Quest Bar - Banana Nut Muffin Natural Protein Bar, 60 g"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "160"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "25"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "5"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "20"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "240"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "2"}], "name": "Quest - Protein Bar Chocolate Peanut Butter, 1 bar (60 g)"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "686"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "59"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "31"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "40"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "1,105"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "9"}], "name": "Grilld - Simply Grilled (Real), 1.25 burger"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "252"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "27"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "14"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "5"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "352"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "1"}], "name": "Grilld - Snack Chips, 1 snack size"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "196"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "15"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "10"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "10"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "176"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "7"}], "name": "Tasti - Salted Caramel Protein Bar, 40 g"}], "sequence": 1}]
```

I am applying the function to extract values like Calories, Carbs, Fat, Protein, Sodium, and Sugar. Here's the code of the function:

```
def fcalories(obj):

 L = []

 data = ast.literal_eval(obj)

 if isinstance(data, list):

   for item in data:

     if isinstance(item, dict):

       if 'nutritions' in item and isinstance(item['nutritions'], list):

         for nutrition in item['nutritions']:

           if isinstance(nutrition, dict) and 'name' in nutrition and nutrition['name'].lower() == 'calories':

             L.append(nutrition['value'])

 return L
```

| Calories |
| --- |
| 412, 170, 176, 342 |
| 112, 175, 376, 122 |

Comment: Show code and other textual information as **properly formatted** text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a json parsing problem:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = json.load(open('x.json'))

out = {}
for meal in data:
    for dish in meal['dishes']:
        gather = {}
        for nut in dish['nutritions']:
            gather[nut['name']] = nut['value']
        out[dish['name']] = gather
    pprint(out)
```

Output:

```
{'Grilld - Simply Grilled (Real), 1.25 burger': {'Calories': '686',
                                                 'Carbs': '59',
                                                 'Fat': '31',
                                                 'Protein': '40',
                                                 'Sodium': '1,105',
                                                 'Sugar': '9'},
 'Grilld - Snack Chips, 1 snack size': {'Calories': '252',
                                        'Carbs': '27',
                                        'Fat': '14',
                                        'Protein': '5',
                                        'Sodium': '352',
                                        'Sugar': '1'},
 'Gu Sports - Chomps, 8 pieces': {'Calories': '180',
                                  'Carbs': '46',
                                  'Fat': '0',
                                  'Protein': '0',
                                  'Sodium': '100',
                                  'Sugar': '22'},
 'Pauls - Smarter White Milk, 600 ml': {'Calories': '342',
                                        'Carbs': '34',
                                        'Fat': '12',
                                        'Protein': '24',
                                        'Sodium': '402',
                                        'Sugar': '34'},
 'Quest - Protein Bar Chocolate Peanut Butter, 1 bar (60 g)': {'Calories': '160',
                                                               'Carbs': '25',
                                                               'Fat': '5',
                                                               'Protein': '20',
                                                               'Sodium': '240',
                                                               'Sugar': '2'},
 'Quest Bar - Banana Nut Muffin Natural Protein Bar, 60 g': {'Calories': '170',
                                                             'Carbs': '25',
                                                             'Fat': '5',
                                                             'Protein': '20',
                                                             'Sodium': '260',
                                                             'Sugar': '2'},
 'Quest Bar - Cookies and Cream, 1 bar': {'Calories': '180',
                                          'Carbs': '22',
                                          'Fat': '7',
                                          'Protein': '21',
                                          'Sodium': '310',
                                          'Sugar': '1'},
 'Tasti - Salted Caramel Protein Bar, 40 g': {'Calories': '196',
                                              'Carbs': '15',
                                              'Fat': '10',
                                              'Protein': '10',
                                              'Sodium': '176',
                                              'Sugar': '7'},
 'Uncle Tobys Australia - Vita Brits, 3 Biscuits 33.3g': {'Calories': '176',
                                                          'Carbs': '33',
                                                          'Fat': '1',
                                                          'Protein': '5',
                                                          'Sodium': '195',
                                                          'Sugar': '0'},
 'my - McDonalds Espresso Pronto® Flat White, 2 TALL': {'Calories': '412',
                                                        'Carbs': '29',
                                                        'Fat': '24',
                                                        'Protein': '21',
                                                        'Sodium': '258',
                                                        'Sugar': '29'}}
```

You can convert the strings to integers, if you like.